# Trace the filename that invoked the macro

Tags: sas, filenames

I use SAS® OnDemand for Academics and what I try to achieve is to get the filename that executed specific macro. Specifically:

I have a `.sas.` script that ha two lines:

```
(test.sas)
%mymacro;
put &myfilename;
```

and a macro that I would like to look like:

```
(mymacro.sas)
%macro mymacro
  %symput("myfilename",xyz) *where xyz is the way to get the file name "test.sas";
%endm
```

What I tried to use are the variables `SAS_EXECFILEPATH` or `SAS_EXECFILENAME` along with the depth variable `sysmexecdepth`

```
%let execpath=%sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH);

%put %sysmexecname(%sysmexecdepth + 1);
```

but no success here. I am sorry for not providing any more tries, but I just have no idea how to do it and I think I cannot squeez anything more from Google.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT 1:
The output of the `%put _ALL_` contains (anonimized):

```
 GLOBAL CLIENTMACHINE STATICLINE31182186166.TOYA.NET.PL
 GLOBAL CUTDTX .
 GLOBAL GRAPHINIT GOPTIONS RESET=ALL GSFNAME=_GSFNAME;
 GLOBAL GRAPHTERM GOPTIONS NOACCESSIBLE;
 GLOBAL HRS 0
 GLOBAL MIN 0
 GLOBAL OLDPREFS homeu000001/.wepreferences
 GLOBAL OLDSNIPPETS homeu000001/.mysnippets
 GLOBAL OLDTASKS homeu000001/.mytasks
 GLOBAL PROJECTDIRPATH /home/u000001/Project
 GLOBAL RUNDT .
 GLOBAL SASWORKLOCATION "/saswork/SAS_work45F100004E32_odaws01-euw1.oda.sas.com/SAS_work6BFC00004E32_odaws01-euw1.oda.sas.com/"
 GLOBAL STUDIODIR homeu000001/.sasstudio
 GLOBAL STUDIODIRNAME .sasstudio
 GLOBAL STUDIOPARENTDIR homeu000001
 GLOBAL SYSCASINIT 0
 GLOBAL SYSSTREAMINGLOG true
 GLOBAL SYSUSERNAME u000001                                                                                                       
                                                                                        
 GLOBAL USERDIR homeu000001
 GLOBAL _BASEURL https:odamideuw1.oda.sas.comSASStudio
 GLOBAL _CLIENTAPP 'SAS Studio'
 GLOBAL _CLIENTAPPABREV Studio
 GLOBAL _CLIENTAPPVERSION 3.81
 GLOBAL _CLIENTMACHINE ---.NET.PL
 GLOBAL _CLIENTMODE wip
 GLOBAL _CLIENTUSERID u000001
 GLOBAL _CLIENTUSERNAME u000001
 GLOBAL _CLIENTVERSION 3.81
 GLOBAL _EXECENV SASStudio
 GLOBAL _MACRO_FOUND 0
 GLOBAL _SASHOSTNAME odaws02euw1
 GLOBAL _SASPROGRAMFILE homeu000001ProjectDirtest.sas
 GLOBAL _SASPROGRAMFILEHOST odaws02euw1
 GLOBAL _SASSERVERNAME SASApp
 GLOBAL _SASWORKINGDIR /pbr/biconfig/940/Lev1/SASApp
 GLOBAL _SASWSTEMP_ homeu59230123.sasstudio.images03976ae74
 GLOBAL _SASWS_ homeu000001
 GLOBAL _METAUSER u000001
 AUTOMATIC AFDSID 0
 AUTOMATIC AFDSNAME 
 AUTOMATIC AFLIB 
 AUTOMATIC AFSTR1 
 AUTOMATIC AFSTR2 
 AUTOMATIC FSPBDV 
 AUTOMATIC SYSADDRBITS 64
 AUTOMATIC SYSBUFFR 
 AUTOMATIC SYSCC 0
 AUTOMATIC SYSCHARWIDTH 1
 AUTOMATIC SYSCMD 
 AUTOMATIC SYSDATASTEPPHASE 
 AUTOMATIC SYSDATE 08SEP21
 AUTOMATIC SYSDATE9 08SEP2021
 AUTOMATIC SYSDAY Wednesday
 AUTOMATIC SYSDEVIC 
 AUTOMATIC SYSDMG 0
 AUTOMATIC SYSDSN FOOTNOTEFOOTNOTE                                                           
 AUTOMATIC SYSENCODING utf-8
 AUTOMATIC SYSENDIAN LITTLE
 AUTOMATIC SYSENV BACK
 AUTOMATIC SYSERR 0
 AUTOMATIC SYSERRORTEXT 
 AUTOMATIC SYSFILRC 0
 AUTOMATIC SYSHOSTINFOLONG Linux LIN X64 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 6 15:49:49 UTC 2019 x86_64 CentOS Linux release 
 7.7.1908 (Core) 
 AUTOMATIC SYSHOSTNAME odaws01-euw1
 AUTOMATIC SYSINCLUDEFILEDEVICE 
 AUTOMATIC SYSINCLUDEFILEDIR 
 AUTOMATIC SYSINCLUDEFILEFILEREF 
 AUTOMATIC SYSINCLUDEFILENAME 
 AUTOMATIC SYSINDEX 14
 AUTOMATIC SYSINFO 0
 AUTOMATIC SYSJOBID 20018
 AUTOMATIC SYSLAST FOOTNOTE.FOOTNOTE
 AUTOMATIC SYSLCKRC 0
 AUTOMATIC SYSLIBRC 0
 AUTOMATIC SYSLOGAPPLNAME 
 AUTOMATIC SYSMACRONAME 
 AUTOMATIC SYSMAXLONG 9007199254740992
 AUTOMATIC SYSMENV S
 AUTOMATIC SYSMSG 
 AUTOMATIC SYSNCPU 2                   
 AUTOMATIC SYSNOBS 2
 AUTOMATIC SYSODSESCAPECHAR 03
 AUTOMATIC SYSODSGRAPHICS 1
 AUTOMATIC SYSODSPATH  WORK.TEMPLAT(UPDATE) SASUSER.TEMPLAT(READ) SASHELP.TMPLMST(READ)
 AUTOMATIC SYSPARM 
 AUTOMATIC SYSPRINTTOLOG 
 AUTOMATIC SYSPRINTTOLIST 
 AUTOMATIC SYSPROCESSID 41DD024117FBF9BE4018000000000000
 AUTOMATIC SYSPROCESSMODE SAS Workspace Server
 AUTOMATIC SYSPROCESSNAME Object Server
 AUTOMATIC SYSPROCNAME 
 AUTOMATIC SYSRC 0
 AUTOMATIC SYSSCP LIN X64
 AUTOMATIC SYSSCPL Linux
 AUTOMATIC SYSSITE 70094220
 AUTOMATIC SYSSIZEOFLONG 8
 AUTOMATIC SYSSIZEOFPTR 8
 AUTOMATIC SYSSIZEOFUNICODE 4
 AUTOMATIC SYSSTARTID 
 AUTOMATIC SYSSTARTNAME 
 AUTOMATIC SYSTCPIPHOSTNAME ---.oda.sas.com
 AUTOMATIC SYSTIME 19:20
 AUTOMATIC SYSTIMEZONE GMT+02:00
 AUTOMATIC SYSTIMEZONEIDENT ETC/GMT-2
 AUTOMATIC SYSTIMEZONEOFFSET 7200
 AUTOMATIC SYSUSERID u59230123
 AUTOMATIC SYSVER 9.4     
 AUTOMATIC SYSVLONG 9.04.01M6P110718
 AUTOMATIC SYSVLONG4 9.04.01M6P11072018
 AUTOMATIC SYSWARNINGTEXT
```

Comment: Did you get the message in the LOG WARNING: The argument to macro function %SYSGET is not defined as a system variable.  You have the right idea but I think you are using the wrong variable.  do %PUT \_ALL\_; to see if there is macro variable that you can use.  The program name is not always available depending on how the code is submitted to SAS.

Comment: indeed there is no %SYSGET and the warning is in the logs. Do you know if there is any workaround?

Comment: did you run %PUT \_ALL\_;?

Comment: I added the result of %PUT _ALL_ in an edit

Comment: Is this the name of your SAS program? GLOBAL _SASPROGRAMFILE homeu000001ProjectDirtest.sas

Comment: This is a path of the file with `/` removed, maybe I will try to use it somehow